# Как получить фото из vk?

Tags: python, django, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Как получить фото из ВКонтакте, используя `python social auth`?

Comment: @hyral, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм в таких ситуациях всегда один - подключаемся, авторизируемся, подключаемся линком (ссылкой) к файлу, потом отдельным классом  скачиваем его. Вас интересует уже написанный код, может?

Comment: Кстати работает ли vk api с украины?